# multiple conditions for a same column

Tags: sql, postgresql

I need to make two conditions for the same column in a Postgres table.

For example here is two queries:

```
select * from product_table where color = 'red';
select * from product_table where color is NULL;
```

How can I  make this in a single query?

Comment: can I use color in ('red', NULL)

Comment: No, do `where color = 'red' or color is NULL`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> This is better

```
select * from product_table where (color = 'red' OR color is null);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try Below Query :

```
 SELECT *  FROM product_table WHERE color IS NULL OR color = 'red' ;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use OR condition for the same like:

```
select * from product_table where color = 'red' OR color is null;
```